# Failed to start Light Display Manager on boot for Ubuntu 20

Tags: nvidia, lightdm, gdm

tl;dr; Light Service DM is not starting. I have tried fixing it via GDM3, was unable to do so due to broken packages. I think that somehow NVIDIA is involved, but I am not sure. Where to start from here?

Hi,

this afternoon I updated some packages. Tried to install gnome-control-center, since my Settings app was missing.
Still was unable to install gnome-control-center, so I tried a reboot.. but then my screen got stuck on

"Starting show plymouth boot screen"

Decided to edit the GRUB file and remove the "no splash", so that I could see the console output while bootup up. There I noticed that the Light Display Manager was not starting. Checked this with `systemctl status lightdm.service` and indeed it failed to start.

Tried re-installing, tried `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm`, tried rebooting.. all did not work.
So another option is to switch to `gdm3`. Well, `gdm3` was not installed and when I tried to I got an error that some packages were not installed. (Since I am on a different computer, I cannot copy-paste the console output.. So I will only state the most important information)

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
gdm3: Depends: gnome-session-bin (but is not going to be installed)
Depends: gnome-shell (but is not going to be installed)
Recommends: xserver-xephyr (but is not going to be installed)
Recommends: xserver-xorg
Recommends: zenity (but is not going to be installed)

I read online that to circumvent the `(but is not going to be installed)` is to do something like

`sudo apt-get install gdm3 gnome-session-bin gnome-shell xserver-xephyr zenity`

But that just gives me a list of MORE dependencies from those packages... which ends up in an almost endless list of dependencies..
In such a case I would hope that `sudo apt install -f` or something along the lines of `--fix-broken` would do the trick.. but to no avail.

Somewhere in my gut I have the feeling that this is the fault of some nvidia driver messing things up.
But when I check my installed driver with `grep "X Driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log` I see that I have version 460 installed (which is also the recommended driver by `ubuntu-driver devices`). However, when I try to check `nvidia-smi` I get as reply "...couldnt communicate with the NVIDIA driver".

Anyway, to conclude... Light Service DM is not starting. I have tried fixing it via GDM3, was stopped by broken packages. I think that somehow NVIDIA is involved, but I am not sure. Where to start from here?

Answer (score 0):

I got to Ubuntu 20.04 via an updated Ubuntu 18.04. I think something went wrong there. I did a fresh install after I did my backup of course.

Now everything works smooth again.